# Add fadein to onscroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using this javascript for the small search icon in the middle of the top nav [here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/events/2014/February/23/remembering-john-denver.html) onscroll:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 120 )
        $("#topSearchIcon").css("display", "block");
    else
        $("#topSearchIcon").css("display", "none");
});

</script>
```

I need to add a fadein for a smoother transition and I'm not sure how best to incorporate it if anyone could help suggest anything? Thanks.

Updated code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 120 )
        $("#topSearchIcon").fadeIn()
        $("#topSearchIcon").css("display", "block");
    else
        $("#topSearchIcon").css("display", "none");
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if ( value > 120 )
        $("#topSearchIcon").fadeIn();
```

You'll want to remove the line:

```
$("#topSearchIcon").css("display", "block");
```

You can see it in action [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadein)

Comment: I've updated my answer. You will need to remove the line below as well